# Hide wordpress widget using conditional tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide a text-widget in wordpress using conditional tags when users are logged in. I've learned that using

`is_user_logged_in()`

shows a text widget when users are logged in.

Comment: Hello. This question is more appropriate to be asked on the [WordPress stackexchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comfortable changing the code where the widget is outputted you could use the **is_user_logged_in()** function. Something like this:

```
<div id="widget_area">
    <?php
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // show nothing
        } else {
            dynamic_sidebar('widget_name');
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

The **downside** being that this is now hard coded and you might have to add this function in a few different files.

So, I'll recommend to use [Widget Logic](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin. Widget Logic is a very popular plugin that will help you accomplish your goal. While Widget Logic can help you do much more than hide or show a widget to logged in/logged out users.

Once installed and activated, you will see an empty box at the bottom of each widget. (**Appearance > Widgets**)